# PartialView does not work properly when called from Layout.cshtml

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core-mvc, dom-events, buttonclick, asp.net-mvc-partialview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoJCW.png) - issue added as it stack overflow is not accepting the code

i am trying to call a partial view(there is a button on the click of which i should be able to close a div .the div is also present in the partial view )from layout file  but its not working.

if i call the partial view in the main page then its working fine.

i have tried all the ways but nothing is working

Comment: smells like javascript problem, see if jquery loaded **before** your notification's js. also, stackoverflow allows people to post code - just add 4 spaces on each line preceeding the code or any indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As normal, partial View is loaded together with the parent view. Therefore, the javascript command should be reside on the parent view rather than the partial view itself.

When you run your code you can see the below error in Console panel(F12 in the browser to check).

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

To globally make the partial view's js work for the view which applied the _Layout,
you could **move** the `jquery` reference to the `head` section of the _Layout.cshtml page and write your custom js code in partial view.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    //add the jquery reference in the head section....
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>    
</head>
```

Comment: The notification has to be used in multiple pages. so in order to avoid writing the code in every page i thought of writing it in the partial view is there any other way in which it should be done ?

Comment: Hi @user3209091,Maybe my answer is not clear to make you understand. yes, by default you need wirte your js in parent page. Because I know you want to write in partial view,  so you just need move the `jquery` reference(<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>) from `body` to the `head` section in _Layout.cshtml, and no need change your partial view.

Comment: its working as i already mentioned ...thankyou so much for your response